# Change the value order of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

i have a table that i created but inserted the wrong values. The actual table is much longer but this will suffice:

| id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 400 |
| 4 | 300 |

and i would like to change the order of all the values of the column `salary`. So basically:

| id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 4 | 100 |

As of now the table is not tied to any constraints. What query would i need to use be able to change the order of the values of a column using a subquery (so that i don't have to manually update all the values)? The data just has to be in reverse order.

I thought of a query like this but it doesnt work:

```sql
UPDATE `t1` 
SET `Salary` = 
    (SELECT `Salary` 
    FROM `t1`
    WHERE `t1`.`id` = `t1`.`id`
    ORDER BY `Salary` DESC);
```

How should the query look like?

(i am using MySQL 5.7)

Comment: What's the logic for the changed order? Is it just the reverse of the original order?

Comment: An id is just an id. Reordering them can create a true mess.

Comment: yes, i just need to reverse it @Barmar

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? I think window functions would be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar i am using mysql 5.7 sadly

Comment: Are there any id gaps?

Comment: Unless the IDs are sequential, this will be difficult in a single query. You could write a script to get arrays of IDs and salaries, then reverse the salary array and do all the updates in a loop.

Comment: @jarlh not in this case, but it would be nice to know how the query would change in that case. I think i would use an inner join but im failing miserably working with the sql syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisz you need a second table with the new data, not all id must be present if they don't change.
As you can not provide an alghorithm which would define the odrdr of the salary, you need a second table, which you can populate.

I used here a temporry table, which will 0only exist in the session, but you canuse a fixed table which you truncate(delet all rows) anfd then fill up

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temtable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `salary` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO temtable
>   (`id`, `salary`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '300'),
>   ('2', '400'),
>   ('3', '200'),
>   ('4', '100');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE origtable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `salary` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO origtable
>   (`id`, `salary`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '100'),
>   ('2', '200'),
>   ('3', '400'),
>   ('4', '300');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE origtable o
> INNER JOIN  temtable t ON t.id = o.id
> SET o.salary = t.salary
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM origtable
> ```
>
> ```
> id | salary
> -: | -----:
>  1 |    300
>  2 |    400
>  3 |    200
>  4 |    100
> ```

> ```
> DROP TABLE temtable
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cf6a892a2f96de262f8552bfbae04eb1)*

Comment: seems like the only way to go. Thanks